# Python - How to get the metadata dictionary of a public Amazon S3 file?

Tags: python, http, dictionary, amazon-s3, metadata

I am trying to get the metadata of a public Amazon S3 file in a public bucket. I have the URL of the file, the bucket name, the filename and even the metadata key ("x-amz-meta-description"). I'm trying to access the metadata for that file, and more specifically the value of that specific key. Is there a way to access that metadata without setting up a full private connection to that bucket?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you should be able to do this with a HTTP `HEAD` request to the object. The [Amazon API docs](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectHEAD.html) indicate that this should return all the metadata entries as `x-amz-meta-*` headers.

Does this help you, or is there a specific library you're using that you need this information from?